# iTextSharp - how to target PDF page number

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I know how to target any text of any PDF page using code:

```
    Anchor click = new Anchor("Click to go to Target");
    click.Reference = "#target";
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
    p1.Add(click);
    doc.Add(p1);

    Anchor target = new Anchor("Target");
    target.Name = "target";
    doc.Add(target);
```

My question is how to target a page based on its number. For example if targeted page number is 6, clicking on the Anchor text should take to 6th page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an `Anchor`, you need a `Chunk`. To this `Chunk` you need to add a `PdfAction`. The action needs to be a [gotoLocalPage()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAction.html#gotoLocalPage%28int,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDestination,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter%29) action.

For instance:

```
Chunk chunk = New Chunk("Go to page 5");
PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(5, New PdfDestination(0), writer);
chunk.SetAction(action);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Go to page 5");
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(highLightFile, FileMode.Create));
        var des = new PdfDestination(0,10f);
        PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(5, des, writer);
        doc.Open();
        chunk.SetAction(action);
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
        p1.Add(chunk);
        doc.Add(p1);
        doc.Close();
```